# Como pegar um array dentro de outro array usando python

Tags: python, json, query, mongodb

estou tentando pegar um array de coordenadas dentro de um outro array em formato de documento JSON, mas estou tendo dificuldades.

Esse é o documento JSON que estou usando

```
{
  "bairro": "Vila Mariana",
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "color": "red"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-46.664488,-23.595191],[-46.664941,-23.593657],[-46.663331,-23.581543],[-46.663972,-23.580556],[-46.661352,-23.579032],[-46.660373,-23.579655],
        [-46.659834,-23.580481],[-46.659682,-23.580653],[-46.653807,-23.583677],[-46.652670,-23.582900],[-46.654226,-23.580491],[-46.651061,-23.578770],
        [-46.651050,-23.579517],[-46.650932,-23.579841],[-46.649569,-23.581227],[-46.641584,-23.575588],[-46.641104,-23.576498],[-46.637409,-23.576827],
        [-46.637585,-23.578800],[-46.637242,-23.578938],[-46.636856,-23.578633],[-46.636287,-23.576303],[-46.635354,-23.575054],[-46.633176,-23.573825],
            [-46.631223,-23.573815],[-46.631502,-23.574228],[-46.632922,-23.574594],[-46.634213,-23.575324],[-46.634095,-23.575560],[-46.633784,-23.575521],
        [-46.633446,-23.575710],[-46.633921,-23.575888],[-46.634779,-23.577306],[-46.633057,-23.579980],[-46.632448,-23.579670],[-46.629101,-23.580181],
        [-46.629090,-23.581587],[-46.628645,-23.581545],[-46.628643,-23.581400],[-46.626203,-23.581671],[-46.626445,-23.581898],[-46.626445,-23.582124],
        [-46.622058,-23.582015],[-46.622047,-23.582359],[-46.622541,-23.582349],[-46.622530,-23.582909],[-46.622058,-23.584187],[-46.622648,-23.584551],
        [-46.622526,-23.585317],[-46.622875,-23.585387],[-46.623519,-23.584512],[-46.626856,-23.584551],[-46.626963,-23.586940],[-46.626244,-23.588267],
        [-46.625708,-23.588296],[-46.625526,-23.588955],[-46.625902,-23.589142],[-46.625430,-23.589545],[-46.627211,-23.589683],[-46.628305,-23.589142],
        [-46.629142,-23.589191],[-46.631717,-23.590341],[-46.631856,-23.591157],[-46.628359,-23.594559],[-46.624818,-23.595473],[-46.625156,-23.596596],
            [-46.622808,-23.597404],[-46.623999,-23.599646],[-46.633591,-23.599666],[-46.633623,-23.601534],[-46.629739,-23.601642],[-46.630361,-23.606587],
            [-46.631498,-23.607314],[-46.632045,-23.606586],[-46.633032,-23.606085],[-46.633404,-23.605470],[-46.635078,-23.605411],[-46.635110,-23.604054],
        [-46.636859,-23.603985],[-46.636752,-23.592669],[-46.639552,-23.593574],[-46.639295,-23.591303],[-46.642026,-23.591343],[-46.645534,-23.590704],
        [-46.645577,-23.590901],[-46.646682,-23.591442],[-46.647422,-23.592818],[-46.652239,-23.591314],[-46.664488,-23.595191]
      ],
      [
            [-46.664588,-23.595291],[-46.665041,-23.593757],[-46.663431,-23.581643],[-46.664072,-23.580656],[-46.661452,-23.579132],[-46.660473,-23.579755],
        [-46.659934,-23.580581],[-46.659782,-23.580753],[-46.653907,-23.583777],[-46.652770,-23.583000],[-46.654326,-23.580591],[-46.651161,-23.578870],
        [-46.651150,-23.579617],[-46.651032,-23.579941],[-46.649669,-23.581327],[-46.641684,-23.575688],[-46.641204,-23.576598],[-46.637509,-23.576927],
        [-46.637685,-23.578900],[-46.637342,-23.579038],[-46.636956,-23.578733],[-46.636387,-23.576403],[-46.635454,-23.575154],[-46.633276,-23.573925],
            [-46.631323,-23.573915],[-46.631602,-23.574328],[-46.633022,-23.574694],[-46.634313,-23.575424],[-46.634195,-23.575660],[-46.633884,-23.575621],
        [-46.633546,-23.575810],[-46.634021,-23.575988],[-46.634879,-23.577406],[-46.633157,-23.580080],[-46.632548,-23.579770],[-46.629201,-23.580281],
        [-46.629190,-23.581687],[-46.628745,-23.581645],[-46.628743,-23.581500],[-46.626303,-23.581771],[-46.626545,-23.581998],[-46.626545,-23.582224],
        [-46.622158,-23.582115],[-46.622147,-23.582459],[-46.622641,-23.582449],[-46.622630,-23.583009],[-46.622158,-23.584287],[-46.622748,-23.584651],
        [-46.622626,-23.585417],[-46.622975,-23.585487],[-46.623619,-23.584612],[-46.626956,-23.584651],[-46.627063,-23.587040],[-46.626344,-23.588367],
        [-46.625808,-23.588396],[-46.625626,-23.589055],[-46.626002,-23.589242],[-46.625530,-23.589645],[-46.627311,-23.589783],[-46.628405,-23.589242],
        [-46.629242,-23.589291],[-46.631817,-23.590441],[-46.631956,-23.591257],[-46.628459,-23.594659],[-46.624918,-23.595573],[-46.625256,-23.596696],
            [-46.622908,-23.597504],[-46.624099,-23.599746],[-46.633691,-23.599766],[-46.633723,-23.601634],[-46.629839,-23.601742],[-46.630461,-23.606687],
            [-46.631598,-23.607414],[-46.632145,-23.606686],[-46.633132,-23.606185],[-46.633504,-23.605570],[-46.635178,-23.605511],[-46.635210,-23.604154],
        [-46.636959,-23.604085],[-46.636852,-23.592769],[-46.639652,-23.593674],[-46.639395,-23.591403],[-46.642126,-23.591443],[-46.645634,-23.590804],
        [-46.645677,-23.591001],[-46.646782,-23.591542],[-46.647522,-23.592918],[-46.652339,-23.591414],[-46.664588,-23.595291]
          ]
    ],
        "type": "Polygon"  
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

o meu principal problema é que estou querendo pegar a primeira list, mas só consigo pegar as duas. Minha aplicação usa MongoDB estou tentando usar a linguagem query deles de busca para isso.

Essa é a parte do código que estou tentando fazer a busca:

```
busca_bairro = bairros.find_one({'bairro': bairro}, {'_id': 0})

        busca_on_circulo = [[lon, lat], 3.10686 / 3963.2]
        busca_no_bairro = busca_bairro['features'][0]['geometry']

        busca_resaturante = restaurantes.find({'location': {
            '$geoWithin': {'$centerSphere': busca_on_circulo,'$geometry': busca_no_bairro}}, 'tipo': {'$all': texto}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, andre! Resolvi o seu problema da seguinte maneira, não sei se é exatamente o que você gostaria, mas talvez te dará alguns insights importantes.

Inicialmente, usei a lib json do python para carregar e tratar os dados. Depois, usei o método load dela para carregar os dados

```
import json
raw_dados = open("dados.json","r")    
dados = json.load(raw_dados)
```

Observe que, caso use a função "type" na varíavel dados, ela te retornará que se trata de um dicionário, sendo assim, devemos fazer as buscas no formato chave/valor

Analisando o JSON, pude observar que as coordenas estão *dentro de uma lista*, cujo a chave é "features", sendo assim, extraí por completo essa lista

```
features = dados["features"]
```

Agora, se você der um print em features, verá que ela não está no formato de dicionário, mas sim, de uma lista. Para tirar ela, basta selecionar o unico elemento dentro dela

```
features = features[0]
```

Agora sim, features é um dicionário!
Basta agora retornar as coordenadas

```
geometria = features["geometry"]
coordenadas = geometria["coordinates"]
```

Suas coordenadas estarão na variável de mesmo nome.

Caso queira dar uma otimizada, poderá ainda fazer da seguinte forma:

```
dados = json.load(dados_raw)
coordenadas = dados["features"][0]["geometry"]['coordinates']
```

Observe que eu apenas juntei toda a busca em apenas uma variavel

Recomendo que dê uma lida na função JSON do python. Ela será muito util para você em diversos casos!
Espero ter te ajudado, qualquer coisa, só chamar!

Documentação da lib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html